# Windows GDI: horizontal/vertical DPI

Tags: c++, c, windows, gdi

When obtaining the DPI for the screen under Windows (by using ::GetDeviceCaps) will the horizontal value always be the same as the vertical?  For example:

```
HDC dc = ::GetDC(NULL);
const int xDPI = ::GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSX);
const int yDPI - ::GetDeviceCaps(dc, LOGPIXELSY);
assert(xDPI == yDPI);
::ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
```

Are these values ever different?

Comment: Not since the 320x200 display mode became obsolete.

Comment: Why assume anything? You already know how to query for both, so why not just query for each of them? You might as well future-proof your code, just in case something comes along that happens to be different!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible for it to be different, but that generally only applies to printers. It can be safely assumed that the screen will always have identical horizontal and vertical DPIs.

Comment: Don't do that. We may have to again contend with non-square pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen them be different, but on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273854(VS.60).aspx) MSDN page I see a comment that suggests that they might be:

```
   int nHorz = dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX);
   int nVert = dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY);

   // almost always the same in both directions, but sometimes not!
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a case where they're different, but the fact that there are two separate calls for it strongly suggests that they might be sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy for them to be different if the monitor is set up to use a screen resolution ratio that is not the same as the physical screen ratio, such as a 4:3 resolution like 1600x1200 on a 16:9 display.

Comment: Even if the physical screen is not displaying square pixels, it is not possible to configure Windows to reflect this fact.